# Error in code, for program that asks input of index for 2d array and outputs the value at that index

Tags: python, arrays, sentinel

I have a task in which I need to do the following:

*Write a program that allows a user to input integer values and query a 2-dimensional array of size 9x9. Your program should then ask the user for a pair of coordinates, (x, y), separated by a space and return the value at the position specified by the given coordinates. For instance, 0 3 should return the value 7 (the value at row one, column four – bearing in mind that array indices start at zero). Assume that each integer is a single digit from 1 - 9. Enter -1 for either coordinate to end the program.*

I keep receiving this error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

this is the code:

```
print("Enter an array:")
array_9x9 = [input() for i in range(9)]    

while True:
    # Read a line of coordinates, split into two elements, convert to integers
    x, y = map(int, input("Enter coordinates: ").split(' ', 2))
               
    # Stop if sentinel in either coordinate
    if -1 in (x, y):
        print("DONE")
        break
    # print the element at the specified coordinates
    print('Value = ' [array_9x9[x][y]])
```

this the output:

```
Sample I/O:
Enter an array:
359716482
867345912
413928675
398574126
546281739
172639548
984163257
621857394
735492861
Enter coordinates:
0 3
Value = 7
Enter coordinates:
5 5
Value = 9
Enter coordinates:
8 8
Value = 1
Enter coordinates:
-1 -1
DONE
```

Comment: The line `map(int, ...)` is doing more at once than you are currently able to understand. Split it into several lines each doing only one thing, to understand where the error happens. This also allows you to print the intermediate values to check whether they correspond to what you expect.

Comment: At what point in the example input and output does the error happen? It looks as if everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling errors that occur when the user inputs invalid values. When prompted if the user simply enters nothing and hits  then you see the error you've described. Likewise, if the user enters non-numeric or unexpected values you'll get a similar error.

```py
while True:
    try:
        x, y = map(int, input("Enter coordinates: ").split(' ', 2))
    except ValueError:
        continue
               
    if -1 in (x, y):
        print("DONE")
        break

    print('Value = ', array_9x9[x][y])  # fixed this line
```

You might also consider additional error handling in case the user enters valid numbers that are invalid indices (e.g. 12 or -2).